# Torch remote debugging

Tags: lua, torch

Is there a way to debug remotely a torch project with any IDE, so that the execution happens in the server (with gpus) and the debugging happens on my laptop, where the IDE is running? 
I've tested ZeroBrane Studio, IntelliJ and Eclipse (with their plugins), but none of them offer this option, though all of them offer nice local debugging.

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak about IntelliJ and Eclipse, but ZeroBrane Studio definitely supports remote debugging with a torch project (assuming the IDE and the application can communicate over sockets); in fact, the local and the remote debugging use exactly the same mechanism. There is a [section on remote debugging](https://studio.zerobrane.com/doc-remote-debugging) in the documentation. You'd need to have `luasocket` for your platform and install the debugger (`mobdebug.lua`). If you run into any specific issues, provide the details so that we can help with them.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out how to do it, as it was not obvious for me coming from remote debugging python with pycharm.
What I have done is starting the server on ZB (which listens at port 8172), create an ssh tunnel to the machines with gpu, and finally running the lua script with the line 'require('mobdebug').start("127.0.0.1")'
via ssh.

I'm not sure how the mapping between the file being run and the file shown in the editor in ZB is done, because the paths don't match, and there's no option to deploy your local project in the server within ZB  studio (and as soultion I use sshfs).